# How to order NUnitLite tests (for integration testing)?

Tags: ios, xamarin, nunit, integration-testing

We are trying to port integration tests that are using NUnit to NUnitLite provided with Xamarin. Some of the tests should run in a particular order. However it looks like there no OrderAttribute or any dependency attribute present in NUnitLite.

Are there any approach for running tests in an order on iOS and Android?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NUnit 2.6.4 and 3.0 runs tests in alphabetical order. Since the Xamarin NUnitLite code is a fork, it **may** behave the same.

Another option is to use [NUnit 3's Xamarin runner](https://github.com/nunit/nunit.xamarin). NUnit 3.2 added an Order attribute and I will be updating the Xamarin runner to use 3.2 shortly. For more information on using the Xamarin runner and NUnit, see [Testing Xamarin Projects using NUnit 3](http://www.alteridem.net/2015/12/21/testing-xamarin-projects-using-nunit-3/)